# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Нужна помощь! Есть проект, TermNet, в нём есть две основные функции, на которых по сути и держится весь код, это функции `authorization()` (авторизация) и `registration()` (регистрация). Так вот, в обеих функциях есть три основные переменные: `login`, `password`, `netkey`. Последняя является неким `ip`-адресом внутри моей локальной сети TermNet-а. В чём суть: при регистрации логин и пароль пользователь придумывает сам, а вот ключ надо генерировать. Ключ выглядит так: `1234:1234:1234:1234`, - это 16-тизначное число, разделённое символом ":" через каждую секцию, состоящую из 4-ёх цифр. Я пробовал следующий код:

```
def genrannetkey():
    a = print(random.randint(1, 9))
    a = a * 4

genrannetkey()
```

Всё взаимодействие с кодом и генерацией происходит через встроенный модуль питона `random`.
кто-нибудь, напишите, пожалуйста, код, который будет случайно генерировать такой ключ, как у меня в примере. Гайды на ютубе по модулю рандом не особо помогают, в интернете помощи тоже особо нет, поэтому обратился.
Вот весь код, на данный момент:

```
# python 3.7.4 Official Release.
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_gui, trange
import pyautogui
import time
import os

def loadbarTermNet():
    for i in trange(100, desc="Connecting...", unit="termcon"):
        time.sleep(0.3)

def registration():
    loginreg = input("Entry a new login: ")
    passreg = input("Entry a new password: ")


def authorization():
    print("Authorization in TermNet.")
    login = input("Login: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    netkey = input("Net Key: ")
    if login == "status1.t3rm":
        if password == "ilisium.is.t3rmc0d3":
            if netkey == "":
                print("Authorization is successfully!")
                loadbarTermNet()
            else:
                print("New to TermNet? Register now!")
                question = input("New to TermNet, wanted to registy?: ")
                if question.lower()[:1] == "y":
                    registration()
                else:
                    print("Then what at is incorrect a data, please retry a attempt.")
                    authorization()
        else:
            print("New to TermNet? Register now!")
            question = input("New to TermNet, wanted to registy?: ")
            if question.lower()[:1] == "y":
                registration()
            else:
                print("Then what at is incorrect a data, please retry a attempt.")
                authorization()
    else:
        print("New to TermNet? Register now!")
        question = input("New to TermNet, wanted to registy?: ")
        if question.lower()[:1] == "y":
            registration()
        else:
            print("Then what at is incorrect a data, please retry a attempt.")
            authorization()
```

---

Обращаюсь к тебе уважаемый @uw935.

Тут возникла проблема. В основном проекте, если пройти авторизацию, всё работает правильно и корректно, но вот с регистрацией возникли проблемы. Отдельно, твой код работает, а вот когда я его интегрировал его в свой код, и соответственно адаптировал его под себя, и под основной код проекта, питон выдал ошибку.

Тест отдельно. Код:

```
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_gui, trange
import time
import random

# a = random.randint(1000, 9999)
# b = random.randint(1000, 9999)
# c = random.randint(1000, 9999)
# d = random.randint(1000, 9999)
#
# print(a, b, c, d, sep=":")

loginreg = input("Entry a new login: ")
passreg = input("Entry a new password: ")
for i in trange(100, desc="Generating random network key(netkey)..."):
    time.sleep(0.2)
a = random.randint(1000, 9999)
b = random.randint(1000, 9999)
c = random.randint(1000, 9999)
d = random.randint(1000, 9999)
randnetkey = print(a, b, c, d, sep=":")
```

Результат:

```
D:\Terminalius\TermNet\$cash>test-random.py
Entry a new login: a
Entry a new password: a
Generating random network key(netkey)...: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:20<00:00,  4.83it/s]
5486:3515:3080:7937
```

Тест в проекте. Код:

```
# python 3.7.4 Official Release.
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_gui, trange
import pyautogui
import time
import os

login = "status1.t3rm"

def genrandnetkey():
    a = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    b = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    c = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    d = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    print(a, b, c, d, sep=":")

def termnet():
    msgbox = input("Input the message: ")
    sendmsg = input("Send?[Y/N]> ")
    if sendmsg == "Y" or sendmsg == "y":
        print(login + ":" + " " + msgbox + "\n")
    else:
        print("Empty message is cannot a sending!")

def loadbarTermNet():
    for i in trange(100, desc="Connecting...", unit="termcon"):
        time.sleep(0.3)
    termnet()

def authorization():
    print("Authorization in TermNet.")
    login = input("Login: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    netkey = input("Net Key: ")
    if login == "status1.t3rm":
        if password == "ilisium.is.t3rmc0d3":
            if netkey == "2020:0208:8080:0808":
                print("Authorization is successfully!")
                loadbarTermNet()
            else:
                print("New to TermNet? Register now!")
                question = input("New to TermNet, wanted to registy?: ")
                if question.lower()[:1] == "y":
                    registration()
                else:
                    print("Then what at is incorrect a data, please retry a attempt.")
                    authorization()
        else:
            print("New to TermNet? Register now!")
            question = input("New to TermNet, wanted to registy?: ")
            if question.lower()[:1] == "y":
                registration()
            else:
                print("Then what at is incorrect a data, please retry a attempt.")
                authorization()
    else:
        print("New to TermNet? Register now!")
        question = input("New to TermNet, wanted to registy?: ")
        if question.lower()[:1] == "y":
            registration()
        else:
            print("Then what at is incorrect a data, please retry a attempt.")
            authorization()

def registration():
    loginreg = input("Entry a new login: ")
    passreg = input("Entry a new password: ")
    for i in trange(100, desc="Generating random network key(netkey)..."):
        time.sleep(0.3)
    a = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    b = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    c = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    d = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    randnetkey = print(a, b, c, d, sep=":")
    with open("datastorage.dat", 'a') as savedata:
        savedata.write(login + "\n")
        savedata.write(passreg + "\n")
        savedata.write(randnetkey + "\n")
    print("Copying it network key for the next of Authorization!")
    print("Do you a have the 10 second.")
    time.sleep(10.0)
    authorization()

authorization()
```

Результат:

```
D:\Terminalius\TermNet>main.py
Authorization in TermNet.
Login: a
Password: a
Net Key: a
New to TermNet? Register now!
New to TermNet, wanted to registy?: y
Entry a new login: hell-o
Entry a new password: 123456
Generating random network key(netkey)...: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:30<00:00,  3.26it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Terminalius\TermNet\main.py", line 83, in <module>
    authorization()
  File "D:\Terminalius\TermNet\main.py", line 59, in authorization
    registration()
  File "D:\Terminalius\TermNet\main.py", line 69, in registration
    a = random.randint(1000, 9999)
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Comment: Зачем плодите дубликаты: [unsupported operand type(s) for \*: 'NoneType' and 'int' - ошибка при print(random.randist(1, 9))](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1302654/unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype-and-int-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-printrando) Хотите что-то изменить или добавить редактируйте оригинальный вопрос кнопкой "править".

Comment: @Roman Konoval, Я конечно в курсе, на форуме уже освоился, просто писать огромный текст, с объяснением что к чему, дело долгое, и монотонное. Здесь я вкратце объяснил проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Добрый вечер.**

Если я правильно конечно понял.)
Если что то не так - пишите.

Решил попробовать сделать, то, что вы написали и у меня получился такой код:

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 1455)
b = random.randint(1, 1455)
c = random.randint(1, 1455)
d = random.randint(1, 1455)

print(a, b, c, d, sep=":")
```

Конечно, что заместо чисел которые у меня указаны в `randint(1, 1455)` можно поставить что угодно.

Comment: Добрый! Ух спасибо, выручили, вместо "1455" подставил нужно мне число, выходит генерация от 1000, до 9999, есть некоторые огрехи, которые я допустил, но работает корректно, спасибо!


`D:\Terminalius\TermNet\$cash>test-random.py
5:7:7:6`

`D:\Terminalius\TermNet\$cash>test-random.py
735:1838:6990:56`

`D:\Terminalius\TermNet\$cash>test-random.py
4637:9663:4785:7227`